# Facebook Developer URL Dubgging Tool Won't Correctly Update

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Using the FB debug tool for http://www.talkjesus.com
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

I fetch new scape info without a problem, except one last thing that just won't kick in. The op:graph image shows default Xenforo pic instead of mine. However, the weird thing is if you click the link, it'll actually show my version (chat icon with 3 people group). It still pulls old XF pic too if I try to post on FB. I've confirmed with XF support it's not them, obviously anyway.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your correct image is at the following URL...

```
http://www.talkjesus.com/styles/default/xenforo/logo.og.png
```

The image Facebook displaying on the Facebook Debug page is a cached copy of your old image. The URL for that image is...

```
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBAyXWZeLwaPVbO&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.talkjesus.com%2Fstyles%2Fdefault%2Fxenforo%2Flogo.og.png
```

The good news is this image caching should not have any effect on how your page is shared on Facebook.

If it does cause problems renaming your image and updating the OG tag will fix it.